# ASP.net - Input string was not in a correct format. for HTMLWorker.ParseToList

Tags: html, asp.net, html-parsing, itext

I am using

> **HTMLWorker.ParseToList(New StringReader(HTMLCode), New StyleSheet)**

On a String **HTMLCode** that contains :

```
  <html>
    <body>
    <table width="auto;">  
        <tr style="color:white ; background: #336699; font-style:bold;">
        <th width="257px;" height="40" >Service Name</th>
        <th width="100px;" height="40">Hits </th>
        <th width="100px;" height="40">Revenue</th>
        <th width="100px;" height="40">Service Cost</th>
        </tr>

        <tr>  
        <td width="257px;" height="30" >  GtalkDay </td> 
        <td width="257px;" height="30" > 320 </td> 
        <td width="257px;" height="30" >  67.20 </td> 
        <td width="257px;" height="30" >  (0.21 K) </td>
        </tr>

        <tr style="background: #EBEBE0">  
        <td width="257px;" height="30" >  TwitterDay </td> 
        <td width="257px;" height="30" > 885 </td> 
        <td width="257px;" height="30" >  185.85 </td> 
        <td width="257px;" height="30" >  (0.21 K) </td>
        </tr>

        <tr>  
        <td width="257px;" height="30" >  YahooDay </td> 
        <td width="257px;" height="30" > 626 </td> 
        <td width="257px;" height="30" >  131.46 </td> 
        <td width="257px;" height="30" >  (0.21 K) </td>
        </tr> 

        </table>
    </body>
    </html>
```

And it is returning the error:

> **Input string was not in a correct format.**

What could be the problem? the HTML code looks perfectly fine.

all Help would be appreciated

*PS: I tried to remove Width and Height and Background attributes and the Parsing worked fine*

Comment: Have you tried using single quotes in place of double quotes?

Comment: @NipunAmbastha Yes and it's still returning the same error... what could be the reason?

Comment: Ok, we can debug it more. i.e. What and where issue is coming?
Take new variable and assign its value New StringReader(HTMLCode); check if this is fine.
Also what you have in stylesheet?

Comment: @NipunAmbastha I tried to remove all the width and background color parameters and the saving to pdf worked fine. Does this mean I can only save plain html?

Comment: Yes, HTMLParser might not accept the tag properties. Probably you will need to search out some other way to create PDF

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might be due to the not proper format of your HTML.

you should remove spaces before the closing tags of you HTML tags as shown below:

**Make change of this,**

```
<td width="257px;" height="30" >  GtalkDay </td>
```

**to**

```
<td width="257px;" height="30">GtalkDay</td>
```